# How to adjust rounding of values in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

The app below works fine. I'm generating the graphs normally, but I'd like to round the values to **graph1**. As it stands, they're not being rounded. For example, if I choose to see 27/06, category ABC, the value 6.5 appears, but I would like to show the value by rounding. Remembering: I want rounded values just for **graph1**. Therefore, could you help me solve this problem?

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shinyWidgets)

function.test<-function(){
  
  df1 <- structure(
    list(date1= c("2021-06-26","2021-06-26","2021-06-26","2021-06-26"),
         date2 = c("2021-06-27","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
         Category = c("ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC"),
         Week= c("Saturday","Wednesday","Thurday","Saturday"),
         DR1 = c(5,4,1,1),
         DR01 = c(8,4,1,0), DR02= c(7,4,2,0),DR03= c(6,9,5,0),
         DR04 = c(5,5,4,0),DR05 = c(5,5,4,0),DR06 = c(7,5,4,0),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),DR08 = c(2,5,4,0)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  
  return(df1)
  
}

f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse, plot = FALSE, var1, var2, gnum=0, graf=1) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    dplyr::filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  if(length(grep("DR0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
    SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
  }
  
  datas <-SPV %>%
    dplyr::filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c(var1,var2)
  datas$days <- datas[[as.name(var1)]]
  datas$numbers <- datas[[as.name(var2)]]
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  m<-df1 %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
  
  m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
  
  if (nrow(datas)<=2){
    val<-as.numeric(m)
  }
  
  else{
    mod <- nls(numbers ~ b1*days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
    coef<-coef(mod)[2]
    val<-as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
  }
  
  
  if(plot){
    
    maxrange <-  range(0, datas$numbers, na.rm = TRUE)
    maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] + 10 
    
    if (gnum) maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] + 40 
    max<-max(0, datas$days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
    limx = c(0,max)
    limy = c(0,maxrange[2])
    if (graf==1){
      if (nrow(datas)<=2) leg = round(m,1) else leg = round(coef,1)
      titl = "The number is:"
    }else if (graf==2){
      if (nrow(datas)<=2) leg = paste('US$', round(m,1)) else leg = paste('US$',round(coef,1))
      titl = " The value is:"
    }
    
    plot(numbers ~ days,  xlim= limx, ylim= limy, xlab = var1, ylab=var2,
         xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
    legend("topright",  legend= leg,title=titl,title.col = "black", cex = 1.2)
    
    if (nrow(datas)<=2){
      abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
      points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
      text(.1,m+ .5, round(m,1), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")

    }
    
    else{
      new.data <- data.frame(days = with(datas, seq(min(days),max(days),len = 45)))
      new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
      lines(new.data$days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
      points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
      text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, round(coef,1)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")

    }
    
  }
  
  return(val)
  
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput("date"),
                                 uiOutput("mycode")),
                               
                               mainPanel(
                                 tabsetPanel(
                                   tabPanel("Graph1", plotOutput("graph",width = "100%", height = "600")),
                                   tabPanel("Graph2", plotOutput("graph2",width = "100%", height = "600"))
                                 )
                               ))
                    )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date2)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    dateInput(input = "date2", 
              label = h4("Choose"),
              min = min(data()$date2),
              max = max(data()$date2),
              value = NA,
              datesdisabled = disabled)
    
  })
  
  output$mycode <- renderUI({
    req(input$date2)
    df1 <- data()
    df2 <- df1[as.Date(df1$date2) %in% input$date2,]
    selectInput("code", label = h4("Category"),choices=unique(df2$Category))
  })
  
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    var1 = "Days"
    var2 = "Numbers"
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code),var1,var2,plot=TRUE, graf=1)
  })
  
  output$graph2 <- renderPlot({
    req(input$date2,input$code)
    var1 = "Reserv"
    var2 = "Weekdays"
    f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code),var1,var2,1,plot=TRUE, graf=2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a new functions called round_0 and round_1.

```
round_0 <- partial(round, digits = 0)
round_1 <- partial(round, digits = 1)
```

then choose one and pass it as the argument `fr` to `f1()`.

```
f1 <- function(df1, dmda, CategoryChosse, plot = FALSE, var1, var2, gnum=0, graf=1, fr) {
    
    x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
    
    x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
    PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
    
    med<-PV %>%
        group_by(Category,Week) %>%
        dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(ends_with("PV"), median))
    
    SPV<-df1%>%
        inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
        mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                          get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                      .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
        select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
    
    SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
    
    mat1 <- df1 %>%
        dplyr::filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
        select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
        pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
        arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
        mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
        dplyr::filter(cs == 0) %>%
        pull(name)
    
    (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
    
    SPV <- SPV %>%
        filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
        select(-any_of(dropnames))
    
    if(length(grep("DR0", names(SPV))) == 0) {
        SPV[head(mat1,10)] <- NA_real_
    }
    
    datas <-SPV %>%
        dplyr::filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
        group_by(Category) %>%
        dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
        pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
        mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
    colnames(datas)[-1]<-c(var1,var2)
    datas$days <- datas[[as.name(var1)]]
    datas$numbers <- datas[[as.name(var2)]]
    
    datas <- datas %>% 
        group_by(Category) %>% 
        slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
            df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(days)+1) %>%
        ungroup
    
    m<-df1 %>%
        group_by(Category,Week) %>%
        dplyr::summarize(dplyr::across(starts_with("DR1"), mean))
    
    m<-subset(m, Week == df1$Week[match(ymd(dmda), ymd(df1$date2))] & Category == CategoryChosse)$DR1
    
    if (nrow(datas)<=2){
        val<-as.numeric(m)
    }
    
    else{
        mod <- nls(numbers ~ b1*days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
        coef<-coef(mod)[2]
        val<-as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
    }
    
    
    if(plot){
        
        maxrange <-  range(0, datas$numbers, na.rm = TRUE)
        maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] + 10 
        
        if (gnum) maxrange[2] <- maxrange[2] + 40 
        max<-max(0, datas$days, na.rm = TRUE)+1
        limx = c(0,max)
        limy = c(0,maxrange[2])
        if (graf==1){
            if (nrow(datas)<=2) leg = fr(m) else leg = fr(coef)
            titl = "The number is:"
        }else if (graf==2){
            if (nrow(datas)<=2) leg = paste('US$', fr(m)) else leg = paste('US$',fr(coef))
            titl = " The value is:"
        }
        
        plot(numbers ~ days,  xlim= limx, ylim= limy, xlab = var1, ylab=var2,
             xaxs='i',data = datas,main = paste0(dmda, "-", CategoryChosse))
        legend("topright",  legend= leg,title=titl,title.col = "black", cex = 1.2)
        
        if (nrow(datas)<=2){
            abline(h=m,lwd=2) 
            points(0, m, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2, xpd = TRUE)
            text(.1,m+ .5, fr(m), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
            
        }
        
        else{
            new.data <- data.frame(days = with(datas, seq(min(days),max(days),len = 45)))
            new.data <- rbind(0, new.data)
            lines(new.data$days,predict(mod,newdata = new.data),lwd=2)
            points(0, coef, col="red",pch=19,cex = 2,xpd=TRUE)
            text(.99,coef + 1,max(0, fr(coef)), cex=1.1,pos=4,offset =1,col="black")
            
        }
        
    }
    
    return(val)
    
}
```

Finally, inside the server modify output$graph*.

```
    output$graph <- renderPlot({
        req(input$date2,input$code)
        var1 = "Days"
        var2 = "Numbers"
        f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code),var1,var2,plot=TRUE, graf=1, fr = round_0)
    })
    
    output$graph2 <- renderPlot({
        req(input$date2,input$code)
        var1 = "Reserv"
        var2 = "Weekdays"
        f1(data(),as.character(input$date2),as.character(input$code),var1,var2,1,plot=TRUE, graf=2, fr = round_1)
    })
```

As an alternative, `floor()` will round to the lowest integer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what is the library for `partial` function? When I run the `round_0`, it appears: `could not find function "partial"`

Comment: `partial` is from `purrr` library, you can load it by `library(tidyverse)` or `library(purrr)`.